# Report Builder Expression - Count Items

Tags: regex, reporting-services

I want to build a report for a SharePoint 2010 list with the Microsoft Report Builder.

Everything works fine with one exception :-(

To count all elements works fine with the following expression:

```
=Count(Fields!Status.Value, "DataSetDocLib")
```

But how can I count the items with a specific name?

I tried lots expressions but nothing works. For example I want to count only the items with the name "Running":

```
=CountDistinct((Fields!Status.Value, "DataSetDocLib"), "Running" ,Recursive)
=Count(Fields!Status.Value Like "Status", "DataSetDocLib")
=CountDistinct(Fields!Status.Value, "Running" ,Recursive, "DataSetDocLib")
```

It is possible and what´s the correct syntax?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I did a small amount of testing and using the following should work:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!Status.Value = "Running", 1, 0)).
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But how can I specify my Dataset with your solution? I tried the following thinks. But it doesen´t work. =SUM(IIF(Fields!Status.Value, "DataSetDocLib" = "Running", 1, 0)) and I tried: =SUM(IIF(Fields!Status.Value = "Running", 1, 0, "DataSetDocLib"))

Comment: Can you give me some more insight of where you are attempting to implement this information? Is it in a text box all by itself?

Comment: I think my field is a field collection and so I must specify the Dataset name as a scope. It doesen´t work without the Dataset name. Your answer is great. But how can I add now the Dataset name to the expression? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283100.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and was helped in another post if anyone stumbles on to this the answer is at the below link

[Report Builder SUM IIF - More than 1 DataSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21603534/report-builder-sum-iif-more-than-1-dataset)

I won't put the answer here so credit goes where it is due (Ian Preston)