# Report Builder SUM IIF - More than 1 DataSet

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I am trying to add the following expression to a TextBox on a Report Builder report using the following code:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!TaskDescription.Value,"DataSet1") = "Running", 1, 0)
```

I have more than 1 dataset which I think is causing the issue, but the above gives me the following error message:

> The scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is equal to
>   either the name of a containing group, the name of a containing data
>   region, or the name of a dataset.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Scope, in your case the DataSet, need to be the last parameter in the aggregate, i.e. after the `IIf`:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!TaskDescription.Value = "Running", 1, 0), "DataSet1")
```

i.e. `=Sum(<Expression>, <Scope>)`

The expression counts the occurrences of the value *Running* in the `TaskDescription` column in the `DataSet1` DataSet.

**Edit after comment**

A quick test showing the expression in action. A simple DataSet with your column:

[image]

[image]

I've just added a textbox to a blank report with the above expression:

[image]

[image]

Works as expected on the sample data:

[image]

Comment: I'm getting the following error using the above: The Value expression for the text box ‘ExecutionTime’ refers directly to the field ‘TaskDescription’ without specifying a dataset aggregate.  When the report contains multiple datasets, field references outside of a data region must be contained within aggregate functions which specify a dataset scope.

Comment: I've shown the expression working as expected - perhaps you have a typo or some such on your side?

Comment: I've checked and double checked, does it work for you if you add another dataset to the report?

Comment: Yes, sorry, added another to make sure and still all fine.

Comment: A new day, a fresh brain...stupidly it is because my TaskDescription is TASKDESCRIPTION. I didn't know it was case sensitive. Thank you for your help.